# Lost data when divide float by 1000

Tags: java

I hava float

```
float data = 24931192;
```

When i divide it by 1000

```
data = data / 1000;
```

it return for me 24931.191. Can anyone tell me why? and how can i prevent it?
Thank you

Comment: Use `java.math.BigDecimal` type.

Comment: Floating Point numbers don't have infinite precision. You will always run into this sort of problem with them eventually. See [this page](http://floating-point-gui.de/) for a fuller discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floats/floating point numbers only have so much precision (23 bits of precision in Java, to be precise), and you just ran into an issue where that precision isn't quite enough. Try using doubles if floats aren't enough, though even those will run into issues eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Floats have limited precision. Here you can read more about how floats are encoded: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point_standard

If you care about precision you should use BigDecimal: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 1):

The floating point data types do not have infinite precision, so you will see small quirks like this. One option (if you really want a float result) is to do the operation with double precision and then cast to float. The other option is to use something like BigDecimal rather than float.

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point values (`float` and `double`) are approximate. You may see rounding errors, and it's actually impossible to represent some values exactly. Think of `1/3 = 0.333333...`: Eventually the storage slots for digits run out, and you end up with `(1/3) * 3 = 0.999999..."

Most uses don't need precise enough answers to need more than a `double`. If you do, look at `BigDecimal`, which is much slower.